# Access form data in multiple actions on same page

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions

I'm trying to access a submitted object from one action in an other action on the same page, while making it available to both actions.
Example: Site /search/ has two plugins embedded:

- SearchPlugin

  - shows search form
  - submits form to itself
- ResultPlugin

  - should get form data from SearchPlugin

Now if I submit the SearchPlugin form data to itself I only have the form data available in the SearchPlugin action, not in the ResultPlugin. If it submit the SearchPlugin form to the ResultPlugin action I only have the data available in the ResultPlugin, not in the SearchPlugin.
I need the data to be available in both plugins/actions on the same site after submitting.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

### Built-in Extbase configuration option

You can use `view.pluginNamespace` to have both plugins use the same HTTP parameter namespace, (e.g. `search` instead of `tx_extension_plugin1`/`tx_extension_plugin2`): https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html

That will make your Extbase actions be able to "share" all parameters. Make sure that all your plugin actions are ready for that.

(Keep in mind though that this "feature" might be deprecated once probably because it adds some architectural burden to efficient resolving of routing configurations. But that is just rumor and I got the idea from here: https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation/TYPO3CMS-Book-ExtbaseFluid/pull/379/files)

### Custom solution

You can manually set up parameters for your Extbase actions in an `initializeAction`:

```php
$pluginContexts = [
  'tx_extension_plugin2',
];
// look for a SearchObject in a different (HTTP) plugin namespace
if (!$this->request->hasArgument('searchObject')) {
    foreach ($pluginContexts as $pluginContext) {
        $foreignPluginContext = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP($pluginContext);
        if (isset($foreignPluginContext['searchObject'])) {
            $searchObject = $foreignPluginContext['searchObject'];
            // if needed do some mapping to object here or validate
            ...            
            $this->request->setArgument('searchObject', $searchObject);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution with the same namespace hast the problem that switchableControllerActions are deprecated, which forces me to use 2 different plugins:
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Deprecation-89463-SwitchableControllerActions.html

Comment: Yes, I am also not using it anymore. The `initializeAction` way is more solid.